# MySQL. Load dump of one table

Tags: php, grep, mysql

I have a big dump MySQL database (1.3 GB). How I may load dump only one table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to command-line, best do it that way if you can:

```
mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#
```

Otherwise use a gui tool like SQLyog (free community edition is available).

Using web-tools will almost definatley prove a huge pain.

To extract a single table, you'll need to manipulate the file, here is a good perl script for it :) http://blog.tsheets.com/2008/tips-tricks/extract-a-single-table-from-a-mysqldump-file.html which I've used successfully in the past.

Comment: This command load all dump_file but I need load only one table from this dump.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/), a script that allows you to import big database or its parts.

You may also use MySQL Workbench, however I cannot confirm it's stability because this tool works very unstable on my CentOS environment.